# How call function in $watch at once?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I $watch in angular directive when content has changed run frame.sly("reload")  function .

But i should do it at once , now after content changes console.log looks like this .

Log
Log(2)
Log(3)
Log(4)
Log(5) ...

And every time it call frame.sly("reload") function more and more times.

```
scope.$watch(

  function () {
     return scope.value;
  },

  function (newValue, oldValue) {
     if (!angular.equals(oldValue, newValue)) {
          $timeout(function() {
              console.log("Log");    
              frame.sly("reload");
          }, 300)
     }

}  ,true);
```

Any ideas ?
Thank in advance.

Comment: Are you maybe asking the log should occur as soon as the change occurs and not delayed?

Comment: You want only once it to be called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deregister `$watch` like this:

```
var watcher = scope.$watch(

  function () {
     return scope.value;
  },

  function (newValue, oldValue) {
     if (!angular.equals(oldValue, newValue)) {
          $timeout(function() {
              console.log("Log");    
              frame.sly("reload");
              watcher();
          }, 300)
     }

}  ,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a easy way to do it

```
var watchVariable= $scope.$watch("Watcher", function () {
// ...
watchVariable();
});
```

This is called as de-registration

Answer (score 0):

You can just add something like `var watchCalled = false` variable and change this value to `true` when the watch called once.

```
var watchCalled = false;

scope.$watch('variableToWatch', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  if (!watchCalled) {
    function () {
      return scope.value;
    }

    function (newValue, oldValue) {
      if (!angular.equals(oldValue, newValue)) {
        $timeout(function () {
          console.log("Log");
          frame.sly("reload");
          scopeCalled = true;
        }, 300)
      }
    }
  }
}, true);
```